# How to add AutoComplete and wildcard capability to function?

Tags: powershell

I have a command called `UpdateModule` that copies modules from a network share to the local modules folder and then reloads the modules.

I'd like to add tab-completion to the modules so that it completes based on the items in `'~\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules'`. Also I'd like to use `UpdateModule *` to update all of the modules.

Comment: Admittedly, this doesn't answer your question, but what you're trying to accomplish sounds a lot like what [PS-NuGet](http://psnuget.codeplex.com/documentation) does. Couldn't hurt to check it out.

Comment: Hacky solution is here http://www.powertheshell.com/dynamicargumentcompletion/

Answer (score 2):

There's no way (yet) to offer "dynamic values" to tab completion. You can hard code values in a parameter validation attribute and tab completion will pick them up:

```
function Test-TabCompletion
{
    param(
        [ValidateSet('module1','module2','module3')]
        [string]$Name       
    )
}

Test-TabCompletion -Name <tab>
```